# How to give different permission for database operation to different user using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying this..
Use access control logic for two user types: administrators and super administrators.

Administrators will have read access to all records within the system however they will have edit/delete access to only those records that are created by them.

Super administrators will have read/edit/delete access to all records.

Comment: Can't you just create a new attribute in the table that has the  value of the person that has created that record?

Comment: manage admin types in database

Comment: create a table which saves user's data such as id and type where type is set as SUPERADMIN and ADMIN and whenever the user logs in, set those values in sessions and voila.

Comment: @Dray - what is voila?

Comment: @Dinesh Gawande there it is; there you are.